# Jenkins freestyle job: validate parameters and/or change the values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In a Jenkins freestyle job I would like to be able to validate parameter values and be able to change the values accordingly to be used in the builds steps.

Imagine having multiple parameters defined and just focus on two of them.
Two string parameters which are presented to the user as input fields:

**ParameterA
ParameterB**

The build process needs one of these parameters to be filled in. Also, they need to be in uppercase.
When both parameters are empty, the build process should fail.
When one of the parameters is filled in, the build process will use one or the other.
When both parameters are filled in, one of them is taken by default and the other one is set to empty.

As the parameter types (having used many plugins offering different types) are very spartan and there is no way in validating fields before starting the build (as we did not press the build now button) there should be a way to achieve this requirement

I was thinking about validating and changing the parameter values in the very first build step.

So I defined a "Execute Windows batch command" to be executed first. This script will check all parameters and fails the build when invalid values are given.

As an example, when a ParameterA is empty but needs a value I check this and exit with error:

```
echo    ${ParameterA} = %ParameterA%

if "%ParameterA%"=="" (
   echo.
   echo ERROR: ParameterA is empty but needs a value
   echo =============PARAM VALIDATION ERROR==================
   echo.
   exit /b 1
)
```

This works fine.

But what about changing values in the script so the build process (build steps after the first one) will take the changed values?

So based on this requirement I have some questions:

Is there a way to validate parameter fields in the pre-build phase so that values can be changed before actually starting the build? For instance to force a string to be uppercase?

How can a build step like the one described above validate parameters and change the values so that further build steps will take the new value? Is this for instance possible using Groovy script as build step or any other plugin giving that option?

I know that pipelines have more options but I would like to enhance my extensive set of jobs which are freestyle to be more resilient and have more control how the parameter data is validated and/or changed in the build process.

I tried to change the variable in the script:

```
if "%ParameterA%"=="" (
   echo.
   echo Warning: ParameterA is empty but needs a value
   echo Using the default value
   SET ParameterA="DEFAULT VALUE"
   echo    ${ParameterA} = %ParameterA%
   echo.
   REM do not fail this step
)
```

The variable is indeed changed in the script and shows the new default value.
But this value is not retained in the main job. So the subsequent build step still uses the old value.

Reading more about this it seems that variables are only accessible and writable within the build step and do not affect the variables outside the script.